# How to use regex to match elements not followed by...?

Tags: regex

How can I match this string?

```
${test {0}}
```

I need to match everything between `${` and `}` where `}` is not preceded by a number, so I can retrieve `test {0}`.

Is it possible to match with a regex pattern alone?

Samples:

```
${any string}              == any string
${string - {x}             == string - {x
${{0} a}                   == {0} a
${a {1} b {3} c {2} d {0}} == a {1} b {3} c {2} d {0}
```

Comment: please explain with the example of matched and not matched data

Comment: And what is desired programming language?

Comment: Why should example #2 match anything at all? It makes no sense...

Comment: @Xaerxess c#. But I want a pattern alone, not a code handling the match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ensure such a criteria using a negative look behind like this

```
\$\{(.*)(?<!\d)\}
```

You can see it online here on [Regexr](http://regexr.com?2ts2v).

Your string is in group 1.

The negative lookahead ensures that it matches only on a `}` that is not preceded by a digit.

Comment: It has one flaw. If the inner string ends with a number it doesn't match (`${a a1}`). But that I can handle. Thanks for your answer, seems to work very well for me and is very readable.

Comment: @Bruno: I think you can fix the flaw like so: `\$\{(.*)(?<!\{\d+)\}`

Answer (score 1):

This works for your test case, but you need to be more clear about how the data you need to capture could vary if you want a better general regex

The regex:

```
/\${(.*[^0-9])}/
```

In Javascript:

```
alert( "${test {0}}".match( /\${(.*[^0-9])}/ )[1] )
```

Comment: why was this voted down? Is there something wrong with the regex?

Comment: I upvoted, but it has one flaw, when the inner string ends with a number it fails. `${test a1}`

Comment: true, I guess I was taking the question too literally rather than trying to understand the intent

Comment: Regex is invalid based on the samples he added afterwards.

Comment: no it isn't, it matches all the sample strings the same as he has put in the question

Comment: test it if you like: `$.each(["${any string}","${string - {x}","${{0} a}","${a {1} b {3} c {2} d {0}}"],function(k,v){ alert( v.match( /\${(.*[^0-9])}/ )[1] ) })`

Answer (score 0):

(Edited following up on your examples...) Like so:

```
/\$\{((?:.+?|\{\d+\})+?)\}/
```

Expect gargantuan backtracking, though...

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<={)([^{}]*({\d+})*[^{}]*)+(?=})
```

It has been tested with RAD Software Regular Expression Designer.. This regex works for .NET and java environment..

You should use this regex for Javascript..

```
{([^{}]*({\d+})*[^{}]*)+}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about : `/\$\{(.*)\}/`

Here is a perl script that do the job with the given examples :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use Modern::Perl;

my @l = ('${any string}','${string - {x}','${{0} a}','${a {1} b {3} c {2} d {0}}');
my $re = qr/\$\{(.*)\}/;
foreach(@l) {
  say $1 if $_ =~ $re;
}
```

**output:**

```
any string
string - {x
{0} a
a {1} b {3} c {2} d {0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which in which language you need this solution but following works for me in PHP:

```
$arr = array('${test {0}}', '${any string}', '${string - {x}', '${{0} a}', '${a {1} b {3} c {2} d {0}}');
foreach ($arr as $s) {
   if (preg_match('~\$\{(.+?[^\d])}~', $s, $m ) > 0)
       var_dump($s . ' == ' . $m[1]);
}
```

#### OUTPUT

```
string(23) "${test {0}} == test {0}"
string(27) "${any string} == any string"
string(29) "${string - {x} == string - {x"
string(17) "${{0} a} == {0} a"
string(53) "${a {1} b {3} c {2} d {0}} == a {1} b {3} c {2} d {0}"
```